# how to know the time taken by each component in mule?

Tags: mule

In my mule project i want to know the time taken by each component in a flow to execute and also the total time taken by a flow to execute.How can i know that.I tried by googling.i found timer interceptor as answer.

But how to configure it to know the datamapper execution time?And also i dont know how to configure it for a flow to know the flow execution time.

Comment: You may print the current system time at the start of flow and the time of exit and take difference

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to message processor notifications and print the before and after timestamps. Take a look at: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Server+Notifications